# Find the next term of the sequence

Tags: cipher, sequence

I created this puzzle. Find the next term of the sequence.

> cjJxa2JyMS9wcHAxcHBwcC8xTjJibjIvQjFucFEyTi8zUDQvOC9QUFAxUFBQUC8xUjFLMUIxUg==
> MmtycWIxci9wcHAxcHBwcC8zbjQvQk4xcDQvbjJQMU4yLzJQMUtRMi9QUDJQUFBQLzFiMVIxQjFSCg==
> MmtyTmIxci9wcHAxcHBwcC8zbjQvMU4xcDFxMi9uQjFQMlExLzJQNS9QUGIxUFBQUC8zUktCMVI=
> MXIzYjFyL3BwcDFwcHBwLzJrNS8xUXFwM2IvMm5QMVIyLzFuUDNOMS9QUEsxUFBQUC80TkIxUg==
> OC9wMXAxcDMvcDJicDJLLzNwMnBwL2tOMVAxUjFQLzJyUTFQUDEvUFAzUDIvOA==
> UTRiMXIvcDFwa3BwcHAvcDRyMi9LMnAzQi8zUDQvNVAxUi9QUDFOMVBQUC8xYlIzbjE=
> OC9wM3AzLzFScE5wMy9wMVE0cC9rMlAycFAvNVBQMS9QMmIxUDIvNUsy
> OC9wM3AzLzJwMXAzL3AxUXAycHAvM1AxYjFQL0s0UFAxL1A0UDFSLzNOMWsy
> MkszTjEvcDNwMy8yUTUvcDFwMXBQMXAvM1AycFAvUDRQUDEvOC8yYjRr

Hint 1:

> Giving a racist advantage?

Hint 2:

> Ephemeral

Hint 3:

> Doctor Who

Bonus:

Why am I special and how am I related to the following image?

> [image: Cryptic_Clue_Bonus]

Note: 'am' refers to the element that continues the above sequence

Comment: the barcode decodes to `4??6+X2`

Comment: @matt That looks like a rot13(cyhf pbqr)

Comment: There's the (absolutely obvious) finding that rot13(gur ryrzragf ner onfrfvkglsbhe-rapbqrq purff SRA cbfvgvbaf. V nz gelvat gb svaq gur tnzrf gurl ner sebz, ohg gung frrzf vzcbffvoyr orpnhfr yvgrenyyl rirelobql nfxf sbe n "Cerzvhz Zrzorefuvc" (jub rira ohlf gurfr?). V (enaqbzyl) fhfcrpg gung gur ynfg DE pbqr vf n cyhf pbqr ercerfragvat gur cynpr jurer gurfr tnzrf jrer cynlrq, jvgu 2 punenpgref ercynprq ol ?.)

Comment: Lbh'er evtug @mypronounismonicareinstate. Ohg jung lbh fnvq nobhg gur cyhf pbqr vfa'g evtug. Gel gb eryngr gur uvagf. Ohg terng thrff gubhtu.

Comment: Yes, @matt and Forgotten_User

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer to lighten the load of future solvers

> The base64 strings all decode to the following FEN chess strings:

> r2qkbr1/ppp1pppp/1N2bn2/B1npQ2N/3P4/8/PPP1PPPP/1R1K1B1R
>  [image]
>
>  2krqb1r/ppp1pppp/3n4/BN1p4/n2P1N2/2P1KQ2/PP2PPPP/1b1R1B1R
>  [image]
>
>  2krNb1r/ppp1pppp/3n4/1N1p1q2/nB1P2Q1/2P5/PPb1PPPP/3RKB1R
>  [image]
>
>  1r3b1r/ppp1pppp/2k5/1Qqp3b/2nP1R2/1nP3N1/PPK1PPPP/4NB1R
>  [image]
>
>  8/p1p1p3/p2bp2K/3p2pp/kN1P1R1P/2rQ1PP1/PP3P2/8
>  [image]
>
>  Q4b1r/p1pkpppp/p4r2/K2p3B/3P4/5P1R/PP1N1PPP/1bR3n1
>  [image]
>
>  8/p3p3/1RpNp3/p1Q4p/k2P2pP/5PP1/P2b1P2/5K2
>  [image]
>
>  8/p3p3/2p1p3/p1Qp2pp/3P1b1P/K4PP1/P4P1R/3N1k2
>  [image]
>
>  2K3N1/p3p3/2Q5/p1p1pP1p/3P2pP/P4PP1/8/2b4k
>  [image]

Comment: What do they signify @micsthepick?

Comment: @JohnBrookfields dunno. The intent was to make it easier for others to figure it out, maybe I'll take another look tomorrow